# Fantasy novel with lighthouse keeper and his daughter

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a lighthouse and a keeper and a daughter, I think.

Our hero goes to lighthouse then rows across the lake and enters a magical land with castles, wizards, etc and adventures

I read it sometime ago but cant remember the title. Is anyone familiar with this?

Comment: There's a checklist [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that will help you improve this question.

Comment: Perhaps. When did you read this? Where? Paperback or hardback? Is the hero the keeper or his (her?) daughter? Were wizards all over the place or rare?

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Right now someone who has read this book could probably identify it, but if you add more details someone who *hasn’t* might be able to.

Comment: This matches a bunch of novels. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sorcerers-Treason-Isavalta-Prologue-Fantasy-ebook/dp/B007ZT1LKW, for example.

Comment: For some reason I am reminded of a Michael Moorcock short, in which a hero goes on a perilous quest that i thought involved rowing across a lake, before dying - the point being that he has pushed back the edge of Chaos a little.